# Use database container or RDS database on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multidocker containers

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am very new to Elastic Beanstalk Multidocker containers, I want something to be clarified.

**Scenario**: In my development environment, I have 3 docker containers - **PHP**, **Nginx** and **MySQL** containers.

**Question:** When deploying my project to *AWS Elastic Beanstalk*, should I deploy my project including MySQL container (Seems easier?), or should I create a new RDS database on AWS? What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the RDS instance instead of a MySQL container. Database scaling, redundancy and backups can be tricky. RDS does that heavy lifting for you. The database is the crown jewel of your stack; unless you're a DBA with experience, I would advise to steer clear of managing a database cluster yourself.